# Average value per minute from second

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My table:

```
timestamp               | value
------------------------+---------
2013-08-31 22:00:01.000 | 19.1
2013-08-31 22:00:03.000 | 21.5
...
```

Due to missing seconds in my data series i want to calculate an average value per minute. So instead of having a data series in seconds I want to have it in minutes instead, like so:

```
timestamp        | value
-----------------+---------
2013-08-31 22:00 | 19.5
2013-08-31 22:01 | 21.1
...
```

How could I write an SQL query that give me this result? I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: To display time like that, you only need to [convert to a string with a mask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).  But it sounds like you might want to calculate something?  If you want to calculate something, you might do it differently than if you want to display it.

Comment: And what is the logic behind of your data transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting from datetime to smalldatetime avoids tedious (and computationally slow) mucking about with date-to-character-back-to-date conversions. The following will calculate the average per minute.

```
SELECT
   cast(Timestamp as smalldatetime)  Timestamp
  ,avg(value)  Value
 from PageLogs
 group by cast(Timestamp as smalldatetime)
 order by cast(Timestamp as smalldatetime)
```

The downsides is rounding; this would convert values between 21:00:30.000 and 22:01:29.997 to 22:00. If you need to average by "calendar" minutes (22:00:00.000 to 22:00:59.997), you'd have to adjust the times (at the millisecond level) to get the right breakpoints, like so:

```
SELECT
   cast(dateadd(ms, -30000, Timestamp) as smalldatetime)  Timestamp
  ,avg(value)  Value
 from PageLogs
 group by cast(dateadd(ms, -30000, Timestamp) as smalldatetime)
 order by cast(dateadd(ms, -30000, Timestamp) as smalldatetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove seconds using `CONVERT()` with format 100:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),100) AS Dt
      ,AVG(value)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),100)
```

You could re-cast as `DATETIME()` if needed:

```
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),100)AS DATETIME)
```

That has seconds/miliseconds but they are all zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Goat CO's answer will work, but if you need the exact date format in your example you need to construct it manually:

```
select
    convert(varchar, datepart(year, ts)) + '-' +
    convert(varchar, datepart(month, ts)) + '-' +
    convert(varchar, datepart(day, ts)) + ' ' +
    convert(varchar, datepart(hour, ts)) + ':' +
    convert(varchar, datepart(minute, ts)) as timestamp,
    avg(value) as value
from
    tbl
group by
    datepart(year, ts),
    datepart(month, ts),
    datepart(day, ts),
    datepart(hour, ts),
    datepart(minute, ts)
```